# For consistency make [sede] a synonym of [data-explorer]

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Across the network the per-site Meta site have tags and questions about the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. We have setup a tag filter to get a feed into some chatrooms when new questions about the Stack Exchange Data Explorer are posted.

A [quick search query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1065299) showed that Writing.Meta is the only site in the Stack Exchange network that has an active [sede](/questions/tagged/sede)  tag instead if the common [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer). On many sites the [sede](/questions/tagged/sede)  tag is a synonym for [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer).

If there isn't a pressing reason why having a data-explorer tag on your meta (with or without the appropriate sede synonym) is a bad idea can you make the needed changes?

As there is only one [question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/can-the-name-of-our-site-in-sede-be-updated) a retag to [data-explorer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) could do.

Answer (score 5):

I asked the question you referred to and edited it to change the tag from [sede](/questions/tagged/sede) to [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer). I wasn't aware of that convention and this looks like a very reasonable request. A synonym would be nice though. Most of the time when I have read about the data explorer it was in combination with the acronym SEDE. But a mod would need to add the synonym.